# Ошибка во время установки imagemin-pngquant

Tags: gulp, npm

Хай, амигос.

```
C:\Projects\Exam>npm i --save-dev imagemin-pngquant
npm WARN package.json myproject@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json myproject@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a bu
ild toolchain, use it instead!
|
> pngquant-bin@3.1.1 postinstall C:\Projects\Exam\node_modules\imagemin-pngquant
\node_modules\pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ‼ connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.36.133:443
  ‼ pngquant pre-build test failed
  i compiling from source
  ? Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:486:12)
imagemin-pngquant@5.0.0 node_modules\imagemin-pngquant
├── is-png@1.0.0
├── exec-buffer@3.0.0 (pify@2.3.0, tempfile@1.1.1, execa@0.3.0)
└── pngquant-bin@3.1.1 (logalot@2.1.0, bin-wrapper@3.0.2, bin-build@2.2.0)
```

Получил такую же ошибку во время установки gulp-imagemin. После чего добавил в etc/hosts строчку `151.101.12.133 sindresorhus.github.io`. Проблема исчезла. С этой проблемой разобраться не могу.

Comment: `make sure that libpng-dev is installed`

Comment: libpng-dev is installed. I think the problem is false to connect due to country hosts blocked. I solve another problem like this with adding addres to hosts file.

Comment: Я говорю по-русски, как и всё сообщество сайта. Я лишь процитировал логи. В вопросе нет информации о том, почему вы так решили, добавьте.